# jQuery - If the body has class rtl do this

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I try to alert message with iquery when body tag has class rtl .I wrote this code :

```
if ($('#Body')).hasclass("rtl"))) { alert("RRRRRRRR TTTTTTTTTTTTTT lllllllllllll");}
```

When I run this don't work anything.

Comment: Braces mismatches `if ($('body').hasClass("rtl"))`

Comment: `if ($('body').hasClass("rtl")) {`?

Comment: Tushar : Thank you .It solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use tag selector, not id selector

```
$('body').hasClass("rtl")
```

Then your code will be like,

```
if ($('body').hasClass("rtl")) {
    alert("RRRRRRRR TTTTTTTTTTTTTT lllllllllllll");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched brackets, along with selection error. You can select the body by directly referencing the element in the selector `$('body')` , no need to catch with an id.

```
  if ($('body').hasClass("rtl")) {

     alert("RRRRRRRR TTTTTTTTTTTTTT lllllllllllll");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

### also make sure that you have set the id attribute of body tag to "body"

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


 if ($("#body").hasClass("rtl"))
    { 
       alert("RRRRRRRR TTTTTTTTTTTTTT lllllllllllll")
    }
});

</script>
```