# How to convert this jquery code to css?

Tags: jquery, css

I try to change float attribute of menu item by css. I want when body tag has rtl class , float of menu items set with right
I wrote this jquery for do this but must done this change before load page .At the result I want do this work with css .

```
if ($('body').hasClass("rtl")) { $('#cssmenu > ul > li').attr('float','right');}
```

Now How to convert this jquery code  to css?

Comment: **Again** just `body`

Comment: `#cssmenu li{float:right}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
body.rtl #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: right;
}
```

The JS code in question has many errors. Here's one if still interested to use JS.

```
$('body.rtl #cssmenu > ul > li').css('float', 'right');
```

Comment: if the body element has `id Body` would it make the code valid?maybe the body has an id of `Body`

Comment: @Pekka Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339473/jquery-if-the-body-has-class-rtl-do-this, OP want to refer to `<body>`, check my comment on question

Comment: I didnt know about the other question my question is if for example we have `<body id=Body></body>` isnt the code a correct. I didnt know about the other question so i posted my comment. For clarification.

Comment: @Pekka As there is only one `body` element, it'll work. Did I answer your question, maybe I don't get you

Comment: @programmer138200 Welcome! Glad to help :)